# Collaboration on Technical Analysis

Tags: united-states, trading, stock-analysis, technical-analysis

I am looking for a community that allows users to share technical analysis thoughts, ideas, and techniques. Is anyone familiar with such a site? I am NOT looking for an article site like motley fool or seekingalpha.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: United States, New York

Comment: Nice question and great topic.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following forums.  Technical analysis discussion can be found on all of these sites:

[EliteTrader](http://www.elitetrader.com/et/index.php)

[Big Mike Trading](https://www.bigmiketrading.com/)

[Traders-Talk](http://www.traders-talk.com/mb2/index.php?)

[HotStockMarket](http://www.hotstockmarket.com/f/)